# Is it possible to launch applications like Chrome from the terminal?

Tags: command-line

I want to launch applications like the web browser using the terminal. What commands do I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use google-chrome, but I went to terminal, and typed "goog-" hitting TAB to autocomplete, it stopped without ending in a space so I knew there were still multple options.  I then hit TAB TAB and could see I could type

`google-chrome`

or

`google-chrome-stable`

on my box (*and I didn't know I had installed google-chrome to being with...  Now i'm off to see when I installed it*)